# Page access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I cannot create page access token, only user access token which expires every 2-3 months.

I created facebook account, page, instagram business account, connected the ig acc with fb page. After that I created developers.facebook app and generated short lived access token (the one that expires in an hour) [permissions and access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK5dT.png). Then I pasted that token and extended it making it expire in 2 months, now when I try a request throug graph API or postman to create a page token, it returns me an empty data[] array[postman request to create a page access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfHtk.png) [https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{fb-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/%7Bfb-user-id%7D/accounts?access_token=%7Buser-access-token%7D) this is a url that I used.

Thanks in advance.